# Auto Increment with decimal MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for a way to Auto Increment a table using decimal(18,0).

Basically I'm building a table to sit the database to hold changes I make to both the database and website. I want to have a table that will return my an ID number like 1.23 or 1.2.3 If this isn't the ID number then that's fine it just has to auto increment when another description is added to my table

My table would be

- ID either standard `int(11) autoincrement` or `decimal(18,0)` if the ID is int(11) then this next field needs to be `decimal(18,0)` but `autoincrement`
- Version Description will be `varchar(100)`
- Version Date `DateTime`

Is there a way this can be done?

Comment: As far as I understand you: no, it can't be done: **Some attributes do not apply to all data types. AUTO_INCREMENT applies only to integer and floating-point types.** see MySQL manual, [CREATE TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html). AUTO_INCREMENT don't apply to DECIMAL.

Comment: "1.2.3" is 'legal numbering'. Can you say a bit more about what you're actually trying to do, and the range(s) of values that might be involved?

Comment: @Strawberry I want to have a table to hold description of my changes I do in the database and on the our site, in doing so I want then to be able to show the ID on the site in the About section. To use an example in older excel version you could click on help and would its version Excel 2010 1.2.3 or something similar. this is what I want to achieve. Getting it to show on the site isnt the issue, its creating a table for me to show it

Comment: So, why does it need to 'increment' - and what does 'increment' even mean in the context of legal numbering?

Comment: Well I thought it would be an easy thing to do, making sure when I complete the next row it would give me a new number, I think i'll just have to type it in manually. Thanks for the help

Comment: I think what I will do is, use the normal ID int(11), auto increment this from a starting point of 100 and when I post that onto the site, I'll split it in the SQL using `CONCAT(LEFT(ID,1),'.',RIGHT(ID,2))` to give me virtually what I want.